# double[,] type, how to get the # of rows?

Tags: c#, arrays

I seem to be getting an odd value.

How do I get the number of rows in my array:

```
double[,] lookup = { {1,2,3}, {4,5,6} };
```

The output should be 2.

Comment: +1 I'd forgotten or did not know that c# supported multidimensional arrays.  Thanks for the reminder.

Comment: I knew of them but I still hadn't any case where I could use them. Maybe in more "mathematical" situations (matrices, vectors, etc.).

Answer (score 18, accepted):

lookup has two dimensions, this is how you can read them

```
double[,] lookup = { {1,2,3}, {4,5,6} };

int rows = lookup.GetLength(0); // 2
int cols = lookup.GetLength(1); // 3    
int cells = lookup.Length;      // 6 = 2*3
```

The concept of **rows** and **cols** is just tradition, you might just as well call the first dimension the columns.

Also see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/586972/how-to-get-multidimensional-length-of-one-axis/587017#587017)

Answer (score 3):

You want the rank property on the array...

```
double[,] lookup = { { 1, 2, 3 }, { 4, 5, 6 } };
Console.WriteLine(lookup.Rank);
```

This will provide you with the number of dimensions.

Edit:
This will only provide you with the number of dimensions for the array as opposed to the number of primary elements or "rows" see @Henk Holterman's answer for a working solution.

Comment: but not the number of rows. See @Henk Holterman's answer for more details.

Answer (score 1):

I think what you're looking for is:

```
lookup.GetLength(0);
```