# Arguments of GetLength()

Tags: c#

What does the Arguments of GetLength mean?
for example

```
value.GetLength(1)
```

where value is a two dimensional Array double[,]
What will changing 0 and 1 differ in?

Comment: It means nothing as there's no such method in the BCL. If this is a standard method provide a link on MSDN to the documentation to remove any ambiguity and if it is your own extension method, please provide source code for it.

Comment: What `GetSize` are you talking about? Where is it found?

Comment: Am I correct in deducing from the `()(1)` that this Getsize is a nullary function returning a unary function? Strange.

Comment: oh sorry! I meant GetLength(1)

Comment: Also see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/677909/double-type-how-to-get-the-of-rows/677955#677955

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The argument for [GetLength](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.array.getlength.aspx) method specifies the dimension. The method returns the number of elements in the specified dimension. Example with a two dimensional array:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        var a = new int[5, 4];
        Console.WriteLine(a.GetLength(0));
        Console.WriteLine(a.GetLength(1));
    }
}
```

prints `5` and `4` on the screen.

Comment: This doesn't make any sense.  To me, this looks like you just returned the value in position 0 and the value at position 1.

Answer (score 2):

`GetLength(i)` returns the number of elements in the `i`th dimension. So for a two-dimensional array `GetLength(0)` returns the number of rows and `GetLength(1)` returns the number of columns.